# LocalDate hora incorrecta

Tags: javascript, nodejs, localdate

Estoy migrando un microservicio desde Java que usa LocalDateTime y, en teoría, debería usar en JavaScript toLocaleString. En Java la respuesta es 2022-10-29T21:59:00 mientras que en Javascript es 2022-10-29T20:59:00.

¿No debería ser la respuesta la misma?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿NodeJS o Java? ¿Qué estás teniendo de backend?

Answer (score 2):

Este "error" se debe a que Javascript tiene en cuenta el **[Horario de verano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horario_de_verano)** por lo que debes incluir el uso horario de tu servidor para obtener el horario exacto.
Te quedaria algo así:

```js
var fecha = new Date();
fecha.setTime(fecha.getTime() - Math.abs(fecha.getTimezoneOffset() / 60));
console.log("Timezone Offset =>",Math.abs(fecha.getTimezoneOffset() / 60))
console.log("Fecha =>",fecha.toLocaleString())
```